# Excepción operando con un grafo( actualizado)

Tags: java, algoritmos

Buenas, estoy modelando un grafo virtual cuya función es minimizar el peso de una nave. Como dice el título de la pregunta, al ejecutar el código me salta esta excepción: "IllegalArgumentException". ¿A qué puede deberse? Aquí adjunto los códigos de las diferentes clases que constituyen el ejercicio.

```
       public class EstadoNave implements VirtualVertex<EstadoNave, SimpleEdge<EstadoNave>> { 
  //CÓDIGO ESTADO NAVE
static List<ObjetoHangar> hangar;
private List<ObjetoHangar> armas_seleccionadas;
private int arma_i;
private List<String> requisitos; //lista de requisitos en el momento


public EstadoNave() {
    //TODO
    armas_seleccionadas= new ArrayList<ObjetoHangar>();
    arma_i=0;
    requisitos=new ArrayList<String>();
}

public EstadoNave(List<ObjetoHangar> armas_seleccionadas, int arma_i, List<String>requisitos) {
    // TODO
    super();
    this.armas_seleccionadas=armas_seleccionadas;
    this.arma_i=arma_i; 
    this.requisitos=requisitos;


}
public List<ObjetoHangar> getArmasSeleccionadas(){
    return armas_seleccionadas;
}

@Override
public boolean isValid() {
    // TODO
    return true;
}

@Override
public Set<EstadoNave> getNeighborListOf() {
    Set<EstadoNave> ret = Sets.newHashSet();

    // TODO
    if(arma_i<hangar.size()){
        EstadoNave es= new EstadoNave(armas_seleccionadas, arma_i+1, requisitos);
        es.armas_seleccionadas.add(hangar.get(arma_i));
        ret.add(es);
        EstadoNave esn= new EstadoNave(armas_seleccionadas, arma_i+1, requisitos);
        ret.add(esn);
    }

    return ret;
}

@Override
public Set<SimpleEdge<EstadoNave>> edgesOf() {
    // TODO
    Set<EstadoNave>vecinos= getNeighborListOf();
    Set<SimpleEdge<EstadoNave>> ret= new HashSet<>();
    for(EstadoNave vecino:vecinos){
        SimpleEdge<EstadoNave> arista=SimpleEdge.<EstadoNave>create(this, vecino);
        ret.add(arista);
    }
    return ret;


}

@Override
public boolean isNeighbor(EstadoNave e) {
    // TODO
    return getNeighborListOf().contains(e);
}

public Integer getDistancia(EstadoNave e){ 
    List<ObjetoHangar> armasprobables= new ArrayList<ObjetoHangar>();
    int i;
    int j;
    for(i=0;i<armasprobables.size();i++){
        ObjetoHangar arma_analizada=armasprobables.get(i);
        for(j=0;i<arma_analizada.getCaracteristicas().size();j++){
            if(requisitos.contains(arma_analizada.getCaracteristicas().get(j))){
                armasprobables.add(arma_analizada);
            }

        }
    }
    //coger mínimo de armasprobables. De todas las armas que he guardado tengo que escoger la que pese menos
    return int)armasprobables.stream().filter(x->x.getPeso()!=null).mapToDouble(x->x.getPeso()).min().orElse(0);

}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "EstadoNave [armas_seleccionadas=" + armas_seleccionadas + ", arma_i=" + arma_i + "]";
}


          public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + arma_i;
    result = prime * result + ((armas_seleccionadas == null) ? 0 : armas_seleccionadas.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((requisitos == null) ? 0 : requisitos.hashCode());
    return result;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    EstadoNave other = (EstadoNave) obj;
    if (arma_i != other.arma_i)
        return false;
    if (armas_seleccionadas == null) {
        if (other.armas_seleccionadas != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!armas_seleccionadas.equals(other.armas_seleccionadas))
        return false;
    if (requisitos == null) {
        if (other.requisitos != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!requisitos.equals(other.requisitos))
        return false;
    return true;
}

     }
```

////GRAFONAVE

```
    public class GrafoNave extends UndirectedSimpleVirtualGraph<EstadoNave, SimpleEdge<EstadoNave>>
    implements AStarGraph<EstadoNave, SimpleEdge<EstadoNave>> {

public static GrafoNave create(EdgeFactory<EstadoNave,SimpleEdge<EstadoNave>> edgeFactory){
    return new GrafoNave(edgeFactory);
}

public GrafoNave(EdgeFactory<EstadoNave, SimpleEdge<EstadoNave>> edgeFactory) {
    super(edgeFactory);
}

@Override
public double getEdgeWeight(SimpleEdge<EstadoNave> e) {
    // TODO 
    return 0;

}

@Override
public double getVertexWeight(EstadoNave vertex) {//tengo que ir recorriendo las armas de la lista de armas_seleccionadas
    //y devolver la suma de los pesos
    // TODO
    double sumapesos = 0;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<vertex.getArmasSeleccionadas().size();i++){
        sumapesos=vertex.getArmasSeleccionadas().get(i).getPeso();
    }

    return sumapesos;
}

@Override
public double getVertexWeight(EstadoNave vertex, SimpleEdge<EstadoNave> edgeIn, SimpleEdge<EstadoNave> edgeOut) {
    // TODO
    return 0;
}


@Override
public double getWeightToEnd(EstadoNave actual, EstadoNave endVertex, Function<EstadoNave, Double> goalDistance,
        Set<EstadoNave> goalSet) {
    // TODO

        if (actual == null || endVertex == null)

            //revisar este método

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("El vÃ©rtice actual y final no pueden ser null");


        // TODO
        double r=actual.getDistancia(endVertex);
        return r;
}

   }
```

////OBJETOHANGAR

```
    public class ObjetoHangar implements Comparable<ObjetoHangar>{

String nombre;
List<String> caracteristicas;
private Float danyo;
private Float peso;

public ObjetoHangar(String id, List<String> caracteristicas, Float peso, Float danyo) {
    this.nombre = id;
    this.caracteristicas = caracteristicas;
    this.peso = peso;
    this.danyo = danyo;

}

public ObjetoHangar(String id, List<String> caracteristicas, Float peso) {
    this.nombre = id;
    this.caracteristicas = caracteristicas;
    this.peso = peso;
    this.danyo = 0f;

}

public String getNombre(){
    return nombre;
}

public Float getDanyo() {
    return danyo;
}
public List<String> getCaracteristicas(){
    return caracteristicas;
}

public void setDanyo(Float danyo) {
    this.danyo = danyo;
}

public Float getPeso() {
    return peso;
}

public void setPeso(Float peso) {
    this.peso = peso;
}

public String toString() {
    return "Arma [id=" + nombre + ", peso=" + peso + ", daÃ±o=" + danyo + "]";
}





@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((caracteristicas == null) ? 0 : caracteristicas.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((danyo == null) ? 0 : danyo.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((nombre == null) ? 0 : nombre.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((peso == null) ? 0 : peso.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (!(obj instanceof ObjetoHangar))
        return false;
    ObjetoHangar other = (ObjetoHangar) obj;
    if (caracteristicas == null) {
        if (other.caracteristicas != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!caracteristicas.equals(other.caracteristicas))
        return false;
    if (danyo == null) {
        if (other.danyo != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!danyo.equals(other.danyo))
        return false;
    if (nombre == null) {
        if (other.nombre != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!nombre.equals(other.nombre))
        return false;
    if (peso == null) {
        if (other.peso != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!peso.equals(other.peso))
        return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(ObjetoHangar o) {
    int res = 0;

    if(this.getPeso() > o.getPeso()){
        res = 1;
    } else{
        res = -1;
    }

    return res;
}





       }
```

///CLASETEST

```
           public class TestViajeInterestelar {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    // TODO: Inicializa el problema hangar y requisitos
    //A) REQUISITOS
    List<String> requisitos= Lists.newArrayList("Laser", "Ligera", "Paralizante",
            "Cuerpo-Cuerpo");
    //B)HANGAR
    List<ObjetoHangar> hangar= new ArrayList<ObjetoHangar>();
    ObjetoHangar arma1= new ObjetoHangar("P-90", Lists.newArrayList("Laser", "Ligera"), 150f, 750f);
    ObjetoHangar arma2= new ObjetoHangar("P-90", Lists.newArrayList("Laser", "Ligera"), 250f, 650f);
    ObjetoHangar arma3= new ObjetoHangar("Disruptor kull", Lists.newArrayList("Paralizante", "Ligera"),
            250f, 500f);
    ObjetoHangar arma4= new ObjetoHangar("Zat", Lists.newArrayList("Laser", "Paralizante", "Cuerpo-Cuerpo"),220f,350f);
    hangar.add(arma1);
    hangar.add(arma2);
    hangar.add(arma3);
    hangar.add(arma4);
    // TODO: Crear estado inicial vacio
    EstadoNave pInicial= new EstadoNave();


    // TODO: Generar function
    Function<EstadoNave, Double> function = (e -> {
        if (requisitos.stream().allMatch(req ->
         e.getArmasSeleccionadas().stream().anyMatch(arma ->
         arma.caracteristicas.contains(req)))) {
        return 0.0;
        } else {
        return Double.MAX_VALUE; //aquí también tengo que revisar
        }
        });

    System.out.println(pInicial);
   // System.out.println(function);

    // TODO: Crear grafo AStart
    AStarGraph<EstadoNave,SimpleEdge<EstadoNave>> graph = new GrafoNave(null);

    // TODO: Crear Algoritmo AStar y le pasamos el grafo, el estado inicial
    // y el function
    AStarAlgorithm<EstadoNave,SimpleEdge<EstadoNave>> alg = Algoritmos.createAStar(graph, pInicial, function);

    if (alg.getPath() == null) {
        System.out.println("No se encuentra soluciÃ³n");
    } else {
        System.out.println(
                "Danyo: " + alg.getPathLength() + ":" + alg.getPath().getEndVertex().getArmasSeleccionadas());
    }
}

     }
```

Se produce al ejecutar el código la siguiente excepción:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Montu, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Para poder responder a tu pregunta es necesario que añadas la información adicional de las clases ObjetoHangar y AStarAlgorithm dado que es en la lógica de estas donde puede ocurrir la excepción. De igual manera ¿en dónde se origina tu excepción y cuál es la traza de esta?

Comment: No creo que el error esté esa clase, pues en ningún momento estás imprimiendo la leyenda "El vértice actual y final no pueden ser null" Además necesitamos más información para resolver tu pregunta pues no sabemos exactamente que necesita realizar tu código. Sin embargo deberías revisar que efectivamente no estés enviando ningún dato nulo además de revisar la lógica de tus condicionales, es lo más que podría decir.

Comment: Estas usando C# cierto?. Esto no parece un error propio del .NET Framework. Si tienes la posibilidad te recomiendo revisar el código de las clases ObjetoHangar y EstadoNave y revisa en que parte se puede estar lanzando este error. O busca en toda tu solución la frase "El vértice actual y final no pueden ser null" y de pronto encuentras una explicación a tu problema.

Comment: El lenguaje que estoy utilizando es Java. Ahora mismo adjunto los códigos de ObjetoHangar, EstadoNave y GrafoNave. La excepción se origina en GrafoNave.

Comment: Para encontrar dragones en código java es esencial de proveer el stackTrace de la excepción. En vez de tirar una propia _IllegalArgumentException_ deberías dejar pasar la NullPointerException que va ocurrir un par de líneas despues y analizar el stackTrace que occurre. Puedes envolver el código en un bloque try-catch por eso y luego usar _printStackTrace()_ para ver donde viene el argumento _null_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas ofuscando tu propio error. Prueba eso:

Cambia en *GrafoNave*:

```
@Override
public double getWeightToEnd(EstadoNave actual, EstadoNave endVertex,
       Function<EstadoNave, Double> goalDistance,
       Set<EstadoNave> goalSet) {
       double r;
       try{
           // TODO

           /**
           if (actual == null || endVertex == null)

           //revisar este método

           throw new IllegalArgumentException("El vÃ©rtice actual y final no pueden ser null");
           **/

           // TODO
           double r=actual.getDistancia(endVertex);
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return r;
```

}

En la consola veras de donde viene tu objeto *null*.

Generalmente es recomendable de no atrapar y ofuscar errores en java ya antes que ocurren.

Ahora que tenemos una excepción podemos analizarlo para encontrar el problema concreta. En este caso no era lo más común (una *NullPointerException*), pero una *NoSuchElementException* que tira la clase *OptionalDouble* de Java8.

Revisando la [API de la clase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalDouble.html), en *getAsDouble()* se tira esta excepción en el caso que el *OptionalDouble* no contiene nada.

Tambien se explica, que *OptionalDouble* "puede o no contener un valor de tipo double".

No he trabajado mucho con los nuevos *Stream* de *Collection* en Java8, así no te podría dar una buena idea donde tu método falla exactamente, pero te puedo dar soluciones como proceder para solucionar el tema.

Revisa en *EstadoNave* el método *getDistancia(...)* :

```
public Integer getDistancia(EstadoNave e){ 
    List<ObjetoHangar> armasprobables= new ArrayList<ObjetoHangar>();
    int i;
    int j;
    for(i=0;i<armasprobables.size();i++){
        ObjetoHangar arma_analizada=armasprobables.get(i);
        for(j=0;i<arma_analizada.getCaracteristicas().size();j++){
             if(requisitos.contains(arma_analizada.getCaracteristicas().get(j))){
            armasprobables.add(arma_analizada);
            }

        }
    }
    //coger mínimo de armasprobables. De todas las armas que he guardado tengo que escoger la que pese menos
    // no se recomienda de no programar en código espagueti, menos si aparecen errores 
    // -- return (int) armasprobables.stream().mapToDouble(x->x.getPeso()).min().getAsDouble();
    Stream<ObjetoHangar> aps = armasprobables.stream();
    DoubleStream ds = aps.mapToDouble(x->x.getPeso());
    OptionalDouble od = ds.min();
    // Ten en cuenta que un cast de double a int no siempre resulta porque double puede ser más grande que un int puede contener
    if (od.isPresent()) return (int) od.getAsDouble();

    // no había mínimo del DoubleStream, aquí puedes analizar lo que no funcionó
    System.out.println(String.format("List len %d, ds elementos %d",
                         armasproblables.length(), ds.count())); 

    // agrega más informaciónes hasta encontrar el error
}
```

Comment: He modificado el código siguiendo sus instrucciones, y la verdad es que por desgracia no me termina de quedar claro cuál es el error que se está produciendo. Adjunto captura justo debajo del código

Comment: Tu problema es que OptionalDouble tira la excepción porque el _Stream_ que estas creando no devuelve un double con _min()_. Deberías refacturar el siguiente código para ver donde tus datos no son lo que esperas:

     return (int) armasprobables.stream().mapToDouble(x->x.getPeso()).min().getAsDouble();

Comment: No sé muy bien cómo debería modificar este return. En este momento, ¿qué devuelve exactamente, si no es un double?¿Qué debería hacer para que el método devolviera un tipo Float, ya que pretendo devolver el peso del arma que pese menos?

Comment: @Montu, te voy a editar la respuesta con los enlaces que necesites para investigar tu problema por ahora. Para el futuro te recomiendo que te acostumbres de leer la documentación de las _API_s que estas usando. Todo lo que necesites saber se encuentra alla.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Modifiqué de nuevo el código de getDistancia(). Debería funcionar bien ya el programa, mas ahora da otra excepción diferente.

Comment: Bueno, ahora ya sabes como encontrar un error con la ayuda del stack trace. ¡Exito!