# Duda excepción en algoritmo grafo virtual

Tags: algoritmos, java-8

Buenas,en este ejercicio se está produciendo un error en el método getWeightToEnd(). Me gustaría saber por qué se produce este error, y qué podría hacer para solucionarlo. Abajo adjunto el determinado método, todo mi código y una captura de la excepción que se produce.

```
  public double getWeightToEnd(EstadoNave actual, EstadoNave endVertex, Function<EstadoNave, Double> goalDistance,
    Set<EstadoNave> goalSet) {
// TODO
 //double r = 0;
    if (actual == null || endVertex == null)

        //revisar este método

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("El vÃ©rtice actual y final no pueden ser null");


    // TODO
    double r =actual.getDistancia(endVertex);



    return r;
       }


  }
```

OBJETOHANGAR:

```
    public class ObjetoHangar implements Comparable<ObjetoHangar>{

String nombre;
List<String> caracteristicas;
private Float danyo;
private Float peso;

public ObjetoHangar(String id, List<String> caracteristicas, Float peso, Float danyo) {
    this.nombre = id;
    this.caracteristicas = caracteristicas;
    this.peso = peso;
    this.danyo = danyo;

}

public ObjetoHangar(String id, List<String> caracteristicas, Float peso) {
    this.nombre = id;
    this.caracteristicas = caracteristicas;
    this.peso = peso;
    this.danyo = 0f;

}

public String getNombre(){
    return nombre;
}

public Float getDanyo() {
    return danyo;
}
public List<String> getCaracteristicas(){
    return caracteristicas;
}

public void setDanyo(Float danyo) {
    this.danyo = danyo;
}

public Float getPeso() {
    return peso;
}

public void setPeso(Float peso) {
    this.peso = peso;
}

public String toString() {
    return "Arma [id=" + nombre + ", peso=" + peso + ", daÃ±o=" + danyo + "]";
}





@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((caracteristicas == null) ? 0 : caracteristicas.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((danyo == null) ? 0 : danyo.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((nombre == null) ? 0 : nombre.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((peso == null) ? 0 : peso.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (!(obj instanceof ObjetoHangar))
        return false;
    ObjetoHangar other = (ObjetoHangar) obj;
    if (caracteristicas == null) {
        if (other.caracteristicas != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!caracteristicas.equals(other.caracteristicas))
        return false;
    if (danyo == null) {
        if (other.danyo != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!danyo.equals(other.danyo))
        return false;
    if (nombre == null) {
        if (other.nombre != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!nombre.equals(other.nombre))
        return false;
    if (peso == null) {
        if (other.peso != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!peso.equals(other.peso))
        return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(ObjetoHangar o) {
    int res = 0;

    if(this.getPeso() > o.getPeso()){
        res = 1;
    } else{
        res = -1;
    }

    return res;
}
```

}

//ESTADOHANGAR

```
    public class EstadoNave implements VirtualVertex<EstadoNave, SimpleEdge<EstadoNave>> {

static List<ObjetoHangar> hangar;
private List<ObjetoHangar> armas_seleccionadas;
private int arma_i;
private List<String> requisitos; //lista de requisitos en el momento

public static EstadoNave create(){
    return new EstadoNave();
}
public EstadoNave() {
    //TODO
    armas_seleccionadas= new ArrayList<ObjetoHangar>();
    arma_i=0;
    requisitos=new ArrayList<String>();
}

public EstadoNave(List<ObjetoHangar> armas_seleccionadas, int arma_i, List<String>requisitos) {
    // TODO
    super();
    this.armas_seleccionadas=armas_seleccionadas;
    this.arma_i=arma_i; //tengo que añadir a estos constructores los requisitos/necesidades
    this.requisitos=requisitos;


}
public List<ObjetoHangar> getArmasSeleccionadas(){
    return armas_seleccionadas;
}


@Override
public boolean isValid() {//está bien
    // TODO
    return true;
}

@Override
public Set<EstadoNave> getNeighborListOf() {
    Set<EstadoNave> ret = Sets.newHashSet();

    // TODO
    if(arma_i<hangar.size()){
        EstadoNave es= new EstadoNave(armas_seleccionadas, arma_i+1, requisitos);
        es.armas_seleccionadas.add(hangar.get(arma_i));
        ret.add(es);
        EstadoNave esn= new EstadoNave(armas_seleccionadas, arma_i+1, requisitos);
        ret.add(esn);
    }

    return ret;
}

@Override
public Set<SimpleEdge<EstadoNave>> edgesOf() {
    // TODO
    Set<EstadoNave>vecinos= getNeighborListOf();
    Set<SimpleEdge<EstadoNave>> ret= new HashSet<>();
    for(EstadoNave vecino:vecinos){
        SimpleEdge<EstadoNave> arista=SimpleEdge.<EstadoNave>create(this, vecino);
        ret.add(arista);
    }
    return ret;


}

@Override
public boolean isNeighbor(EstadoNave e) {
    // TODO
    return getNeighborListOf().contains(e);
}

public Integer getDistancia(EstadoNave e){ 
    List<ObjetoHangar> armasprobables= new ArrayList<ObjetoHangar>();
    int i;
    int j;
    for(i=0;i<armasprobables.size();i++){
        ObjetoHangar arma_analizada=armasprobables.get(i);
        for(j=0;i<arma_analizada.getCaracteristicas().size();j++){
            if(requisitos.contains(arma_analizada.getCaracteristicas().get(j))){
                armasprobables.add(arma_analizada);
            }

        }
    }
    //coger mínimo de armasprobables. De todas las armas que he guardado tengo que escoger la que pese menos
    return (int)armasprobables.stream().filter(x->x.getPeso()!=null).mapToDouble(x->x.getPeso()).min().orElse(0);
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "EstadoNave [armas_seleccionadas=" + armas_seleccionadas + ", arma_i=" + arma_i + ", requisitos="
            + requisitos + "]";
}
```

}

GRAFONAVE

```
      public class GrafoNave extends UndirectedSimpleVirtualGraph<EstadoNave, SimpleEdge<EstadoNave>>
             implements AStarGraph<EstadoNave, SimpleEdge<EstadoNave>> {

         public static GrafoNave create(EdgeFactory<EstadoNave,SimpleEdge<EstadoNave>> edgeFactory){
    return new GrafoNave(edgeFactory);
}

      public GrafoNave(EdgeFactory<EstadoNave, SimpleEdge<EstadoNave>> edgeFactory) {
    super(edgeFactory);
}

@Override
public double getEdgeWeight(SimpleEdge<EstadoNave> e) {
    // TODO 
    return 0;

}

@Override
public double getVertexWeight(EstadoNave vertex) {//tengo que ir recorriendo las armas de la lista de armas_seleccionadas
    //y devolver la suma de los pesos
    // TODO
    double sumapesos = 0;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<vertex.getArmasSeleccionadas().size();i++){
        sumapesos=vertex.getArmasSeleccionadas().get(i).getPeso();
    }

    return sumapesos;
}

@Override
public double getVertexWeight(EstadoNave vertex, SimpleEdge<EstadoNave> edgeIn, SimpleEdge<EstadoNave> edgeOut) {
    // TODO
    return 0;
}


@Override
public double getWeightToEnd(EstadoNave actual, EstadoNave endVertex, Function<EstadoNave, Double> goalDistance,
        Set<EstadoNave> goalSet) {
    // TODO
     //double r = 0;
        if (actual == null || endVertex == null)

            //revisar este método

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("El vÃ©rtice actual y final no pueden ser null");


        // TODO
        double r =actual.getDistancia(endVertex);



        return r;
}


      }
```

CLASETEST

```
             public class TestViajeInterestelar {
               public static EstadoNave pInicial;

//public static EstadoNave pObjetivo;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // TODO: Inicializa el problema hangar y requisitos
    //A) REQUISITOS
    List<String> requisitos= Lists.newArrayList("Laser", "Ligera", "Paralizante",
            "Cuerpo-Cuerpo");
    //B)HANGAR
    List<ObjetoHangar> hangar= new ArrayList<ObjetoHangar>();
    ObjetoHangar arma1= new ObjetoHangar("P-90", Lists.newArrayList("Laser", "Ligera"), 150f, 750f);
    ObjetoHangar arma2= new ObjetoHangar("P-90", Lists.newArrayList("Laser", "Ligera"), 250f, 650f);
    ObjetoHangar arma3= new ObjetoHangar("Disruptor kull", Lists.newArrayList("Paralizante", "Ligera"),
            250f, 500f);
    ObjetoHangar arma4= new ObjetoHangar("Zat", Lists.newArrayList("Laser", "Paralizante", "Cuerpo-Cuerpo"),220f,350f);
    hangar.add(arma1);
    hangar.add(arma2);
    hangar.add(arma3);
    hangar.add(arma4);
    // TODO: Crear estado inicial vacio

    pInicial=EstadoNave.create();

    // TODO: Generar function
    Function<EstadoNave, Double> function = (e -> {
        if (requisitos.stream().allMatch(req ->
         e.getArmasSeleccionadas().stream().anyMatch(arma ->
         arma.caracteristicas.contains(req)))) {
        return 0.0;
        } else {
        return Double.MAX_VALUE; //aquí también tengo que revisar
        }
        });

    System.out.println(pInicial);
   // System.out.println(function);

    // TODO: Crear grafo AStart
    AStarGraph<EstadoNave,SimpleEdge<EstadoNave>> graph = GrafoNave.create(SimpleEdge::create);

    // TODO: Crear Algoritmo AStar y le pasamos el grafo, el estado inicial
    // y el function
    AStarAlgorithm<EstadoNave,SimpleEdge<EstadoNave>> alg = Algoritmos.createAStar(graph, pInicial, function);

    if (alg.getPath() == null) {
        System.out.println("No se encuentra soluciÃ³n");
    } else {
        System.out.println(
                "Danyo: " + alg.getPathLength() + ":" + alg.getPath().getEndVertex().getArmasSeleccionadas());
    }
}
```

}
Adjunto captura de la excepción que se produce al ejecutar el código de esta forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: De acuerdo, edito añadiendo el error que se produce

Comment: Esas definiciones las incluí en otra pregunta que me surgió con respecto a este ejercicio. Muchas gracias por su ayuda, soy novato en el sitio y voy aprendiendo poco a poco: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42741/excepci%C3%B3n-operando-con-un-grafo

Comment: De acuerdo, ahora mismo voy. Es que no sabía si podía incluir ese código aquí también.

Comment: He modificado este error, y ahora me sale otro: el método getArma_I() no está definido para el tipo Float.

Comment: Está el método getNombre(), nombre es el id del arma. En el constructor de ObjetoHangar se ve esto, hay una línea que es this. nombre=id. Es que ahora que me doy cuenta he cometido un error, implementé getArma_I() en EstadoNave.

Comment: Sí, de hecho eso iba a comentar, lo que pasa es que he tenido que esperar 5 minutos para hacerlo. Antes me he liado haciendo el ejercicio. Lo que tengo que hacer es, como el método getDistancia() devuelve un Integer, devolver el peso del arma que pese menos. Lo que me despista es que el peso de ObjetoHangar es de tipo Float, así que no sé muy bien cómo hacerlo, antes lo intenté con la siguiente instrucción pero no funcionaba correctamente: return (int) armasprobables.stream().mapToDouble(x->x.getPeso()).min().getAsDouble();

Comment: No me dio los resultados esperados; cuando ejecutaba el programa saltaba una excepción, he adjutado en la pregunta una captura de ella. Me comentaron que lo que ocurría es que OptionalDouble tiraba la excepción porque el Stream que estaba creando no devolvía un double con un min(). Así que tengo que modificar este return antes de probar con un try and catch para ver de donde venía un objeto null

Comment: ¿La excepción no se produce por un error en el método getDistancia()?

Comment: Vale, ya entiendo lo que ha pasado, arriba no adjunté el código de GrafoNave. Grave error mío. Ahora mismo lo arreglo. Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con respecto a la sentencia (siendo que dices que allí está el error):

```
return (int) armasprobables.stream().mapToDouble(x->x.getPeso()).min().getAsDouble();
```

Esto te puede generar 2 errores diferentes:

1. `java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present` si `armasprobables` está vacío.
2. `java.lang.NullPointerException` si `getPeso()` devuelve `null` para una arma en la lista.

Te tocará decidir que quieres hacer en esas situaciones.

Por ejemplo, si la lista está vacía, tal vez quieras devolver algún valor como `0`. Esto lo puedes hacer usando el método [`orElse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalDouble.html#orElse-double-) en vez de `getAsDouble()`:

```
return (int) armasprobables
    .stream()
    .mapToDouble(x -> x.getPeso())
    .min()
    .orElse(0); // devuelve el mínimo, o 0 si la lista está vacía.
```

Y en cuanto a pesos que están a `null`, tal vez desees ignorarlos. Esto lo puedes hacer filtrando el stream con [`filter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) para ignorar los pesos que están a `null`:

```
return (int) armasprobables
    .stream()
    .filter(x -> x.getPeso() != null) // ignora pesos a null
    .mapToDouble(x -> x.getPeso())
    .min()
    .orElse(0); // devuelve el mínimo, o 0 si la lista contiene solo nulls o está vacía.
```

## Edición

Ahora que has incluído mas información en cuanto al error + stack trace, queda claro que el error **no sucede donde lo indicastes**.

El error y el stack trace están claritos. El error sucede en la clase `GrafoNave` en el método `getWeightToEnd()` en la porción siguiente:

```
if (actual == null || endVertex == null)

            //revisar este método

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("El vÃ©rtice actual y final no pueden ser null");
```

... ya la razón es obvia. Una de las variables `actual` o `endVertex` está a null. El mensaje está más que claro.

O sea que nunca llega a ejecutarse el método `getDistancia()`.

Te tocará averiguar por qué `actual` o `endVertex` están a null y arreglar eso. Una vez que lo hagas, ahora sí, se ejecutará el método `getDistancia()` y puede que lo que te comenté más arriba te sirva.

Comment: Agregué una edición a la respuesta. Pero te voy a ser franco, ne me agrada la forma como le has dado vueltas a la pregunta para que al final quede claro que el error no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta. Por favor repasa este enlace detenidamente: [mcve], y esmérate por seguir esos consejos para tu próxima pregunta.

Comment: De acuerdo, siento mucho las molestias y de nuevo le doy las gracias por su paciente ayuda.